# Can Visual Studion print some expressions on breakpoint?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I Java IDEs I had ability to print any Java expression from withing breakpoint. In C# Visual Studio I see

[image]

which prints text as is, without interpreting it.

Can I have feature like in Java?

Comment: In short, we can print a generic string, to include the value of a variable or expression. You could get much more detailed information here:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/10/06/new-breakpoint-configuration-experience-in-visual-studio-2015/ or here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: Not get your response for several days, did you resolve this issue? Any update, feel free to share it here.